# Select/Barrier statements in $\pi$-Calculus denotational semantics

Tags: concurrency, semantics, category-theory

A `select` statement waits on $n$ channels until channel $0$ or $1$ or ... or $n-1$ have data.

A `barrier` lock waits on $n$ channels until channel $0$ and $1$ and ... and $n-1$ have data.

These two constructs seem to mirror co-product and product, respectively, in category theory. While I know there are category theory interpretations of the $\pi$-Calculus, are there any that make this distinction? Are other concurrency tools derivable in a similar way (blocking queue, fork & join, etc.)?

It doesn't have to be $\pi$-Calculus; are there other category-based theories for concurrency can derive these everyday constructs?